# String escape, reading from text file

Tags: javascript, string, file-io, escaping

I have a text file with this content:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

I am trying to read this simple content with php and put it into a div using JavaScript.
Everyting is okay but if I add a break line to text, it doesn't work.

```
Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet
```

This files are uploaded to server by users, not written by app.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "read.php",
    data: '',
    success: function(response)
    {
        $("div#content").html(response);
    }
    });
```

If it contains some special chars, doesn't work again.

```
Lorem ipsum 'dolor sit amet'
```

Comment: When you say, "it doesn't work", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: It just doesn't put the content into div. I've treid to use try..catch but doesnt throw an error..

Comment: HTML is not the same as text.

Comment: What do you see in the debugger & the DOM inspector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your PHP:

```
echo json_encode($your_string);
```

That should take care of escaping newlines for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need use a text...

```
  $("div#content").text(response);
```